# How to make a 90s Cel animated look in blender

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, animation-nodes, 2d

[image: Anime Girl]

I'm trying to created the Cel animated look in blender but with 2D animation beside, mimicking the style from the 80s and 90s I feel like theirs some nuance to it that I need to set up nodes for. Theirs also something about the inking that just a regular black line doesn't capture like the colors painted behind it have some influence how could i recreate that?

Im also trying to add a super faint drop shadow to the main character against the background which I think could help, but I also don't know how to do that.

[image: Akira cell]
I'm new to blender and don't really know how to work the nodes super well so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Learn the nodes!  docs.blender.org -> Render Engines -> Materials. Also, this question has been asked a lot of different ways before now. Check out the MP-Lab addon on GitHub as their anime characters implement this fairly well.

Comment: I mean professional anime artists in Japan already have a hard time making good looking 3D anime, I doubt you'll achieve anything like that with 3D modelling Blender. Cinema 4D has a bit more toon shading options, but realistically, learning 2D animation IS the way to go. You can then use Grease Pencil in Blender to draw 2D characters.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this video last night and this question today. If you haven't found or created a solution, hopefully this helps:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsvZsVPhTVs

Comment: Please include relevant details in your answer. Link-only answers are less then ideal, because the content could become unavailable or change to when the answer was posted.